# Graph Generation through shell script

Tags: shell, unix, graph

I have a script on place which is fetching the CPU & Memory usage of the server via shell script and sending the output to .txt file under the same server.

I would like to make a some sort of graph or something which can show usage in graph etc after getting the output into the file.

Can anyone please help or suggest a way if this thing is possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

hope this would help: [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).

> Gnuplot is a free, command-driven, interactive, function and data plotting program.